# Silverlight Map Tiler

Tags: silverlight

I just started learning Silverlight and onTop of that I have to create a map viewer that displays our map tiles. I have search EVERYWHERE online and cant find anything that helps me. All Im looking for is a way to Display the tiles and have it draggable so that it starts pulling off more Tiles from the server. I'd like to build it from scratch but im not sure where to begin. I've looked at the whole microsoft BING thing but that doesnt help as its too much of BINGS's own stuff. Going in circles looking everywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

The control you are looking for is `MultiScaleImage` control.  This allows not only for an image to be composed of tiles but also various zoom levels.  Its worth taking the time to read the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc645050(VS.95).aspx) on this control.

Comment: Deep Zoom looks perfect. It looks towards making a DZI file to display the images. BUt thats a bit beyond my reach as the file size would be enourmous for it to slice up. Is there a way to set the images manualy and in order in an MultiScaleImage control? I noticed that the source looks for a .bin file ? Sorry still learning this as fast as I can :P

Comment: You've managed to pick a particularly prickly problem to solve as your first use of Silverlight.  Yes it is possible to manually add and remove as well move Tile items in a MultiScaleImage control.  What you would be looking to do is implement your own `MultiScaleTileSource`

Comment: After doing more research (still couldnt really figure out that multyscaletilesource thing :P ) Im not sure if the Deepzoom thing will work for what I need as it has a pyramid effect with less image tiles as you go up in zoom levels. The map system I am working on has the same amount of Images per zoom level. Its a case of "when zoom in to 0.5" it just changes the images path to there and then pulls the X and Y co-ordinated Images. Working on a map system that is exactly like maps.google.com but for our country and needs of course.. We're looking into making it a silverlight app.

Comment: Yes DeepZoom may not do things the way you need, thats why I've indicated that you need to create an implementation of `MultiScaleTileSource` that suits your specific needs.  However fundementally understanding how deep zoom and multiscale imaging works is paramount if you going to stand a chance of acheiving this.  Once you throughly understand how these and related classes achieve what they do you will be in a position to tailor a solution to your needs.